# What will be the Regular expression for matching a constant word ending with number

Tags: javascript, regex

The string's I want to match are like -

```
'RANDOM1', 'RANDOM2', 'RANDOM78'
```

Here the word **RANDOM** is constant always ending with a number.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use LINK: https://regex101.com/ to create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var str='RANDOM1';
if(/^RANDOM\d+$/gi.test(str))
  console.log('true');
else
  console.log('false');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match word RANDOM from start of the line (`^`)and one or more characters after that (`+`)

Comment: op did not say the constant word would be at the beginning of the line always.

Answer (score 0):

you got downvoted for not showing any effort

RANDOM[0-9]+

is a regex that will trap what you look for.